# Unable to detect adb version when attempting to use uiautomatorviewer, no exit value

Tags: android, automation, adb, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to use uiautomatorviewer to capture my Android device which is connected via usb.
I have uninstalled Android SDK and re-installed. I have no problems with adb commands such as install or connect etc. As you can see below, I am able to see the device attached with adb devices command and I am able to see the adb version when using adb version command. The problem is that when I launch uiautomatorviewer I run into
Unable to detect adb version, adb output:
At this point nothing else happens and the program does not connect to my device.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> adb devices
List of devices attached
a2738481        device

PS C:\Windows\system32> adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.3-6597393
Installed as C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
PS C:\Windows\system32> uiautomatorviewer
03:55:06 E/adb: Unable to detect adb version, adb output:
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Thinking possibly something is wrong with my uiautomatorviewer.bat file

```
@echo off
rem Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
rem
rem Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
rem you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
rem You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem
rem      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem
rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
rem limitations under the License.

rem don't modify the caller's environment
setlocal

rem Set up prog to be the path of this script, including following symlinks,
rem and set up progdir to be the fully-qualified pathname of its directory.
set prog=%~f0

rem Change current directory and drive to where the script is, to avoid
rem issues with directories containing whitespaces.
cd /d %~dp0

rem Get the CWD as a full path with short names only (without spaces)
for %%i in ("%cd%\..") do set prog_dir=%%~fsi

rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
call ..\lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF

for /f %%a in ("%APP_HOME%\lib\uiautomatorviewer-26.0.0-dev.jar") do set jarfile=%%~nxa
set frameworkdir=.

if exist %frameworkdir%\%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
    set frameworkdir=..\lib

if exist %frameworkdir%\%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
    set frameworkdir=..\framework

:JarFileOk

set jarpath=%frameworkdir%\%jarfile%

if not defined ANDROID_SWT goto QueryArch
    set swt_path=%ANDROID_SWT%
    goto SwtDone

:QueryArch

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%frameworkdir%\..\bin\archquery') do set swt_path=%frameworkdir%\%%a

:SwtDone

if exist "%swt_path%" goto SetPath
    echo SWT folder '%swt_path%' does not exist.
    echo Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
    exit /B

:SetPath
set javaextdirs=%swt_path%;%frameworkdir%

call "%java_exe%" "-Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs%" "-Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=C:\android-sdk\tools" -jar %jarpath% %*
```

Note that when I run monitor.bat in C:\android-sdk\tools it works without any issues

Answer (score 0):

-I removed and reinstalled Android SDK
-I tried previous older SDKs
-tried powershell and command prompt
-removing and adding path to environment variables
The only thing that finally fixed my issue was re installing windows.
But hey, at least now it works!